# Regex to find even occurrence of a character in a string every time it repeats in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, regex, string

Regex to find even occurrence of a character in a string every time it repeats in a string

Example:

```
YYMMDD-YYYY-DD true
YYMDD false
```

Y,M,D are case sensitive Y,M,D can appear multiple time at multiple postion in pairs in string but each pair must be even.

I have applied the above even check using for loop but have to replace for loop with regex
I have also tried it with the below regex but it didn’t worked

```js
if (result.match(/M{2,}/) || result.match(/D{2,}/) || result.match(/Y{2,}/)) {}
```

[solution using for loop which i have implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZKP1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
[ 'YYMMDD-YYYY-DD', 'YYMMDD', 'YYMDD', 'Y', 'YY', 'YYY', 'YYYY', 'XX' ].forEach(str => {
  let ok = /^(?:([YMD])\1-?)+$/.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + ok);
});
```

Output:

```
YYMMDD-YYYY-DD => true
YYMMDD => true
YYMDD => false
Y => false
YY => true
YYY => false
YYYY => true
XX => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?:` -- non-capture group start
- `([YMD])` -- capture group 1: single alpha character
- `\1` -- repeat capture group 1
- `-?` -- optional `-` (if needed change to a character class to allow additional chars)
- `)+` -- non-capture group end, repeat 1+ times
- `$` -- anchor at end

Comment: Only Y,D,M characters are allowed in the string

Comment: @unknown: Ah, good point, regex tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

```js
re = /^(?:([A-Z])\1|[^A-Z])+$/

console.log(re.test('YYMMDD-YYYY-DD'))
console.log(re.test('YY'))
console.log(re.test('YYY'))
console.log(re.test('YYYY'))
```

`/^(?:([A-Z])\1|[^A-Z])+$/` = ( (letter + the same letter once again) OR non-letter ) repeat once or more